# Using verbs of motion, how to ask "How do I get to Red Square?"

Tags: глаголы

How to ask and which are the best ways to say "How do I get to Red Square?" using verbs of motion and respective prepositions

Comment: What verbs of motion do you think are appropriate in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are on foot:

> Как пройти на Красную площадь?

If you are driving a car:

> Как проехать на Красную площадь?

Universal way:

> Как попасть на Красную площадь?

As you can see the pattern is:

> Как (мне/нам) *verb_of_motion* на Красную площадь?

Comment: I'm not sure about попасть - is it a verb of motion? The phrase itself is ok however.

Comment: I believe it is a verb with a meaning of motion in this case.

Comment: Just splitting hairs here: 'verb of motion' is often used to refer to the specific set of verbs that distinguish multidirectional vs unidirectional motion (ходить - идти, водить - вести, etc.). So попасть isn't a verb of motion in that sense, though its meaning certainly has to do with motion.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try, 
"Как мне добраться до Красной площади?"
It is closer to the word 'get'

Comment: Blackmoor, can добраться also be used for "make it"? For instance, if Andrey leaves a bar drunk and you wonder if he made it home safely, ¿could you say: Интересно, добрался ли Андрей домой.